# Uncaught ReferenceError: insertRecord is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I would like to submit the form and access the sql script in insertRecord.  But I get this error message in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: insertRecord is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Here is my form:

```
<form method="get" id="student_form">
   First Name:<input class="form-control" type="text" name="f_name" value="">
  <button type="submit" form="student_form"  value="Submit" class="btn" onclick="insertRecord">Enroll</button>
</form>



public void insertRecord(String f_name)
{
openConnection();


            // Create insert command.
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO " +
               "student_folio(f_name)VALUES(:f_name)", connection);


            // Add paramaters.
            command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("f_name",
                NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Char));


            // Prepare the command.
            command.Prepare();


            // Add value to the paramater.
            command.Parameters[0].Value = f_name;

       Execute SQL command.
            int recordAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(recordAffected))
            {
                showInformation("Data successfully saved!");
            }


        closeConnection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
public void insertRecord(String f_name)
{
*insert query*
}
```

into this

```
public void insertRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       string first_name = f_name.text.toString();


       // Create insert command.
       NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO " +
           "student_folio(first_name)VALUES(:first_name)", connection);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I edit the block of *insert query* a moment ago.  After using the (object sender, EventArgs e) it gave me this error -- The name 'f_name' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: of course it gives you error because you have not declare the `f_name` it is different from the `name = f_name`

Comment: so where should I declare that?  sorry im quiet new in this

Comment: you can declare it in `eventHandler` see my updated answer

Comment: Error: User of unassigned local variable 'f_name'

Comment: change it into `first_name`

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the value of Insert_Rec() method parameter named f_name  in the onclick event.Otherwise remove the parameter in the function and do the dom manipulation related variable value using javascript.